VS2022 ASP.NET + React: Unable to launch the previously selected debugger. Please choose another
I have created an ASP.NET + React.js project in Visual Studio 2022. I inserted an existing React.js app into client side. The client uses Next.js (if it is relevant). When I try to run it, I get the following issues:


If I continue, it runs normally. I can access both ASP.NET and React.js app, but I cannot debug React.js app. How can I choose another debugger if that's what the issue is?
